# php startup: unable to load dynamic library''php5.5.12/ext/modulename.extension'- the spacified module could not be found

Tags: php, database, extjs, phpmyadmin, php-5.5

I removed the folder `www` to uninstall my `wampsever 5.4.3`, and I install a new one with `PHP v5.5.12` but when I start up, I get a message:

```
php startup: unable to load dynamic library''php5.5.12/ext/modulename.extension'- the spacified module could not be found
```

But when I test with `localhost`, it's okay.

I tested it with `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`, it's okay, but when I test with my project, it's doesn't display with PHP code processes fetched from database, but for HTML is okay.

Any help please!